# How to send an object from a thymeleaf form to MVC spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have two classes (Employee and Project) that have many to many relationship. I am trying to send the contents of the thymeleaf form with the (project) as the class object and a drop down list that contains the employee list. I can retrieve the employee list in my form but when I submit it to the controller to save it, non of the employees in the list saved. I should be able to save one employee each time I submit the form.

This is Employee class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "DOB")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dob;

    @Column(name = "HIRING_DATE")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date hiringDate;

    @Column(name = "TERMINATION_DATE")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date terminationDate;

    @Column(name = "TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "JOB_TITLE")
    private String jobTitle;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER_ID")
    private Employee manager;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private EmployeeInfo empInfo;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "EMPLOYEE_PROJECT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID") })
    Set<Project> projects;


    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String telephone, String email, String jobTitle) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }


    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public Date getHiringDate() {
        return hiringDate;
    }

    public void setHiringDate(Date hiringDate) {
        this.hiringDate = hiringDate;
    }

    public Date getTerminationDate() {
        return terminationDate;
    }

    public void setTerminationDate(Date terminationDate) {
        this.terminationDate = terminationDate;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    public Employee getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(Employee manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public EmployeeInfo getEmpInfo() {
        return empInfo;
    }

    public void setEmpInfo(EmployeeInfo empInfo) {
        this.empInfo = empInfo;
    }

}
```

This is Project class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PROJECT_TYPE")
    private String projectType;

    @Column(name = "PROJECT_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "END_DATE")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date endDate;

    @Column(name = "COST")
    private Float cost;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Employee> employees;


    public Project() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProjectType() {
        return projectType;
    }

    public void setProjectType(String projectType) {
        this.projectType = projectType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public Float getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(Float cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }


}
```

This is the main projects page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Projects List</h2>
        <a href="#" th:href="@{/projects/new}" class="btn btn-primary"
            role="button">Add New Project</a> <br> <br>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Project Type</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>

            </tr>
            <tr th:each="project : ${projects}">
                <td th:text="${project.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${project.cost}"></td>
                <td th:text="${project.startDate}"></td>
                <td th:text="${project.endDate}"></td>
                <td th:text="${project.projectType}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{'/project/' + ${project.id} + '/update'}">Update</a></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{'/project/' + ${project.id} + '/addTeam'}">Add Team</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the thymeleaf view:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h1>
            <span th:text="${project.name }" th:remove="tag">title</span>
        </h1>
        <h3>
            <span th:text="${project.id }" th:remove="tag">title</span>
        </h3>
        <br>
        <h2>Add Project Team</h2>
        <br>

        <form class="form-group" th:object="${project}"
            th:action="@{/projects/saveProject}" method="post">
            <input th:type="hidden" name="id" th:field="${project.id}" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="employees">Add Team:</label> 
                <select name="employees"
                    id="employees">
                    <option th:each="data:${employeesList}" th:value="${data.id}"
                        th:text="${data.firstName}" >Options</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

            <a href="#" th:href="@{/projects}" class="btn btn-danger"
                role="button">Cancel</a>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("project/{id}/addTeam")
    public String addProjectTeam(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("project", projectService.findById(Long.valueOf(id)));
        model.addAttribute("employeesList", this.employeeService.getEmployees());
        return "addTeam";
    }

    @PostMapping("/projects/saveProject")
    public String saveOrUpdate(Model model, @RequestParam("project") Project project,
            @RequestParam("employees") Set<Long> employeesIds)

    {
        Set<Employee> employees = new LinkedHashSet<Employee>();
        if (project.getEmployees() != null && project.getEmployees().size() > 0) {
            for (Employee emp : project.getEmployees()) {
                employeesIds.add(emp.getId());
            }
            for (Long eId : employeesIds) {
                Employee e = this.employeeService.findById(eId);
                employees.add(e);
            }
            project.setEmployees(employees);
            this.projectService.saveProject(project);

        }
        model.addAttribute("projects", projectService.getProjects());

        return "redirect:/projects/";enter image description here
    }
```

I appreciate your help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently you want to send the 'Employee' object from HTML-Drop-down to your Controller , which you're not able to get.!!
If thats the case here , as per your code - You haven't set 'Employee' object in your  thymeleaf code, Also I'd like to tell you that you wont be able to get all the values like dob,job_title,address from your 'Employee' class on the drop down because a HTML drop-down contains name and its value only. Something like this

```
<select name="Employee">
    <option value="Id">David</option>
    <option value="Id">Peter</option>

  </select>
```

In order to solve this problem , send your 'Employee-Id' & 'employee-name' from controller to thymeleaf and then further after getting the 'Employee-Id' object on your controller , execute a 'select query' to get the details of the employee from DB.
For that:---

1.) From your controller where you're sending the Employee & Project's Object use Model Attribute like this :--

```
   @RequestMapping("/getProjectAndEmployee")
    public String getProjectAndEmployee(Model model) {

    List<YourEmployeeEntityClass> employees = //your code to get the employee 
    List<YourProjectEntityClass> project = //your code to get project 

         model.addAttribute("employees",employees);
         model.addAttribute("project",project);

}
```

2.) (Now this part is important) Get the Employee ID and Employee name on your Thyemleaf Code along with project :---

```
<select>
     <option th:each="data:${employees}" th:value="${data.employee_id}" th:text="${data.employee_name}"> </option>
  </select>
```

3.) Get the list of selected Employee_id & Project_details on your controller like this  :--

```
@PostMapping("/projects/saveProject")
    public String saveOrUpdate(Model model, @RequestParam("project") Project project, 


         @RequestParam("employee_id")String employee_id ) {

           //here you've employee_id , get the employee's details on the basis of this id from your DB

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I apologize for not sending the complete information to get the exact answer. Please check the code again. I included the main projects html page and the right addTeam html page. Thanks again for help.

Comment: @Hasan
I could see here that you're trying to get the employees object in Java's Set in your controller.
I'm not sure weather you can do it directly, cz in order to get values in Set or Map from your HTML to Spring Controller you need to convert it intp JSON or String Format first.
What you can do is try to get the employee id in String in your Controller .
Here :--
 

@PostMapping("/projects/saveProject")
    public String saveOrUpdate(Model model, @RequestParam("project") Project project,
            @RequestParam("employees") String employeesIds)

Comment: and now to get rid of your problem of getting Duplicate employee's id :--

1.)  you can use SQL-UNIQUE clause while selecting the list of employees to send it further to your Thymeleaf/HTML.

2.) or you can convert/add your employee_id in Set after getting employee's object.

Whichever suits you.